# React - Tela preta em exibição de modal

Tags: javascript, react

tudo bem ?

Estou com um problema de exibição de um modal em um component react, acontece que quando clicamos para apresentar a exibição do modal a tela fica escura e acaba travando o navegador [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No código eu tenho os seguintes trechos:

Menu responsável por chamar o modal:

```
<li><button type="button" onClick={this.showModal}>Import File</button></li>
```

Função:

```
showModal = () => { this.refs.modal.show() }
```

Parte do componente:

```
<Modal className="swagger-ui modal" ref="modal">
          <div className="container">
            <h2>Upload file</h2>
            <input type="file" ref="fileLoadInput"></input>
          </div>
          <div className="right">
            <button className="btn cancel" onClick={this.hideModal}>Cancel</button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={this.importFromFile}>Open file</button>
          </div>
        </Modal>
```

Não consigo descobrir o motivo que está gerando o problema, alguém conseguiria dar uma força ?

Comment: Trava o navegador ou apenas mostra essa tela escura?

Comment: Acredito que a ação da tela ficar escura conforme eu mostrei na imagem é um comportamento normal do css do modal, a questão é que trava totalmente o navegador e não abre o conteúdo do modal.

Comment: Trava o navegador ao ponto de ter que fecha-lo e abrir de novo?

Comment: Ele trava o nagevador, mas se eu der um refresh a execução da página volta a funcionar, porém ele não abre o modal... o problema acontece só quando é requisitado a abertura do modal pelo link do menu

Comment: Tenta colocar um `z-index: 9999;` na modal.

Comment: Não funciona... O problema parece que está relacionado ao import de um determinado component, se eu retiro o import dele, tudo volta a funcionar... isso faz algum sentido ?

Comment: ixi, não sei dizer pq não entendo de react.

Comment: Tenta debugar pelo browser, coloca um breakpoint exatamente na hora que você clica no button que chama o this.showModal e vê se você consegue chegar até o ponto que ele para.